# Having issue when pick image from gallery in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter.
I am using the following to pick the image from the gallery.
At first time, I am getting the mentioned exception.
After getting the exception, If I resize the image, I don't face any issue for loading the image.
I am not sure what makes the issue.

**GetImage**

```
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery );

   setState(() {
     if(pickedFile != null){
       _image=File(pickedFile.path);
       print(_image.path);
     }else{
       print("no Image selected");
     }

   });
```

**Show Image**

```
class CameraChild extends StatelessWidget{
  String imagePath = null;

  CameraChild(File image){
    if(image != null){
      imagePath = image.path;
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    AssetImage assetImage;
    if(imagePath == null){
      assetImage=AssetImage('images/camera_child.png');
    }else{
      assetImage=AssetImage(imagePath);
      
    }
    Image image = new Image(image: assetImage, width: 90, height: 90,);
    //return Container(child: image,);
    return Container(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
        child: image,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Exception:**

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.sixdrops.drmom/cache/image_picker1457837975547141122.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0 PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)

#1 AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
#2 AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
#3 ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "/data/user/0/com.sixdrops.drmom/cache/image_picker1457837975547141122.jpg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#2ea2b(), name: "/data/user/0/com.sixdrops.drmom/cache/image_picker1457837975547141122.jpg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
W/System (24478): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System (24478): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System (24478): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Comment: use FileImage instated of  AssetImage in else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File image instead of Asset Image.

```dart
return Container(
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
    child: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
  ),
);
```